# Replacing the query string in the URL generated by PagedList with custom URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, url-routing, pagedlist

I am using PagedList in a fully functional pager and it is generating the query string for the indexed pages as expected.

I wanted to know if there is a way the URL could be customized to eliminate the query string and add another Route parameter instead.

The following is my View :-

```
@model PagedList.Core.IPagedList<ActionAugerMVC.Models.Review>
@using PagedList.Core.Mvc;
@addTagHelper *, PagedList.Core.Mvc

<div id='Paging' style="text-align:center">
     Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
     <pager class="pager-container" list="@Model" 
            options="@PagedListRenderOptions.TwitterBootstrapPager" 
            asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Review" />
</div>
```

And here is my Controller Action :-

```
[Route("Reviews/calgary-tech-reviews")]
public IActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageIndex = 1;
    pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;

    var review = unitOfWork.ReviewRepository.GetAll();
    return View(review.OrderByDescending(m=> m.Date).ToPagedList(pageIndex,pageSize));
}
```

The current URL looks like this :-

```
http://localhost:63613/Reviews/calgary-tech-reviews?page=2
```

And I want it to look like this :-

```
http://localhost:63613/Reviews/calgary-tech-reviews/page-2/
```

OR

```
http://localhost:63613/Reviews/page-2/calgary-tech-reviews/
```

Any assistance would be appreciated, as I am still new this !
Thanks once again !

Answer (score 0):

On `Startup.cs` file, method `Configure`, add a route to get that parameter:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //...
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        //...
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "paged",
            template: "{controller=Reviews}/{action=Index}/page/{page=1}");
    });
 }
```

Now you can open: `http://localhost:63613/Reviews/calgary-tech-reviews/page/2/`

I couldn't set it to work with `page-{page=1}`, only with `page/{page=1}`. `page` always returns `0` in the first case.

If you can make it work, please let me know. =)

Comment: let me try that, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It does not seem to affect anything, even with the Route decorators removed.